# React Native - onPress firing wrong event

Tags: react-native, touchableopacity, onpress, panresponder

I'm trying to make a rotating Rubik's cube that has each small cube as a touchable component that fires an event - Touching cubes on the Orange, Green and Yellow fire the correct events whereas touching some cubes on the other colours ends up firing events on one of these 3 (Orange/Green/Yellow) colours.
How do I fix this?

This is App.js:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import {
  Dimensions,
  PanResponder,
  View,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Text,
} from 'react-native';
import { transformOrigin, rotateXY, rotateXZ } from './utils';

import SmallBox from './SmallBox';

const HEIGHT = Dimensions.get('window').height;
const WIDTH = Dimensions.get('window').width;

const styles = {
  container: {
    position: 'absolute',
    left: WIDTH / 2 - 50,
    top: HEIGHT / 2 - 50,
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
  },
  rectangle: {
    position: 'absolute',
    left: 0,
    top: 0,
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    zIndex: 10,
  },
  smallBox: {
    height: 100 / 3,
    width: 100 / 3,
    borderWidth: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
};

export default class Cube extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    this.panResponder = PanResponder.create({
      onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
      onPanResponderMove: this.handlePanResponderMove.bind(this),
    });
  }

  handlePanResponderMove(e, gestureState) {
    const { dx, dy } = gestureState;
    const origin = { x: 0, y: 0, z: -50 };
    let matrix = rotateXY(dx, dy);
    transformOrigin(matrix, origin);
    this.refViewFront.setNativeProps({
      style: { transform: [{ perspective: 1000 }, { matrix: matrix }] },
    });

    //test
    matrix = rotateXY(dx + 180, dy);
    transformOrigin(matrix, origin);
    this.refViewBack.setNativeProps({
      style: { transform: [{ perspective: 1000 }, { matrix: matrix }] },
    });

    matrix = rotateXY(dx + 90, dy);
    transformOrigin(matrix, origin);
    this.refViewRight.setNativeProps({
      style: { transform: [{ perspective: 1000 }, { matrix: matrix }] },
    });

    matrix = rotateXY(dx - 90, dy);
    transformOrigin(matrix, origin);
    this.refViewLeft.setNativeProps({
      style: { transform: [{ perspective: 1000 }, { matrix: matrix }] },
    });

    matrix = rotateXZ(dx, dy - 90);
    transformOrigin(matrix, origin);
    this.refViewTop.setNativeProps({
      style: { transform: [{ perspective: 1000 }, { matrix: matrix }] },
    });

    matrix = rotateXZ(-dx, dy + 90);
    transformOrigin(matrix, origin);
    this.refViewBottom.setNativeProps({
      style: { transform: [{ perspective: 1000 }, { matrix: matrix }] },
    });
  }

  renderRight(color) {
    return (
      <View
        ref={(component) => (this.refViewRight = component)}
        style={[styles.rectangle, color ? { backgroundColor: color } : null]}
        {...this.panResponder.panHandlers}
      >
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
          <SmallBox num={1} color='yellow' position='top-left' />
          <SmallBox num={1} color='yellow' position='top-middle' />
          <SmallBox num={1} color='yellow' position='top-right' />
        </View>
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
          <SmallBox num={1} color='yellow' position='middle-left' />
          <SmallBox num={1} color='yellow' position='middle-middle' />
          <SmallBox num={1} color='yellow' position='middle-right' />
        </View>
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
          <SmallBox num={1} color='yellow' position='bottom-left' />
          <SmallBox num={1} color='yellow' position='bottom-middle' />
          <SmallBox num={1} color='yellow' position='bottom-right' />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }

  renderLeft(color) {
    return (
      <View
        ref={(component) => (this.refViewLeft = component)}
        style={[styles.rectangle, color ? { backgroundColor: color } : null]}
        {...this.panResponder.panHandlers}
      >
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
          <SmallBox num={1} color='blue' position='top-left' />
          <SmallBox num={1} color='blue' position='top-middle' />
          <SmallBox num={1} color='blue' position='top-right' />
        </View>
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
          <SmallBox num={1} color='blue' position='middle-left' />
          <SmallBox num={1} color='blue' position='middle-middle' />
          <SmallBox num={1} color='blue' position='middle-right' />
        </View>
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
          <SmallBox num={1} color='blue' position='bottom-left' />
          <SmallBox num={1} color='blue' position='bottom-middle' />
          <SmallBox num={1} color='blue' position='bottom-right' />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }

  renderFront(color) {
    return (
      <View
        ref={(component) => (this.refViewFront = component)}
        style={[styles.rectangle, color ? { backgroundColor: color } : null]}
        {...this.panResponder.panHandlers}
      >
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
          <SmallBox num={1} color='red' position='top-left' />
          <SmallBox num={1} color='red' position='top-middle' />
          <SmallBox num={1} color='red' position='top-right' />
        </View>
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
          <SmallBox num={1} color='red' position='middle-left' />
          <SmallBox num={1} color='red' position='middle-middle' />
          <SmallBox num={1} color='red' position='middle-right' />
        </View>
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
          <SmallBox num={1} color='red' position='bottom-left' />
          <SmallBox num={1} color='red' position='bottom-middle' />
          <SmallBox num={1} color='red' position='bottom-right' />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }

  renderBack(color) {
    return (
      <View
        ref={(component) => (this.refViewBack = component)}
        style={[styles.rectangle, color ? { backgroundColor: color } : null]}
        {...this.panResponder.panHandlers}
      >
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
          <SmallBox num={1} color='green' position='top-left' />
          <SmallBox num={1} color='green' position='top-middle' />
          <SmallBox num={1} color='green' position='top-right' />
        </View>
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
          <SmallBox num={1} color='green' position='middle-left' />
          <SmallBox num={1} color='green' position='middle-middle' />
          <SmallBox num={1} color='green' position='middle-right' />
        </View>
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
          <SmallBox num={1} color='green' position='bottom-left' />
          <SmallBox num={1} color='green' position='bottom-middle' />
          <SmallBox num={1} color='green' position='bottom-right' />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }

  renderTop(color) {
    return (
      <View
        ref={(component) => (this.refViewTop = component)}
        style={[styles.rectangle, color ? { backgroundColor: color } : null]}
        {...this.panResponder.panHandlers}
      >
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
          <SmallBox num={1} color='white' position='top-left' />
          <SmallBox num={1} color='white' position='top-middle' />
          <SmallBox num={1} color='white' position='top-right' />
        </View>
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
          <SmallBox num={1} color='white' position='middle-left' />
          <SmallBox num={1} color='white' position='middle-middle' />
          <SmallBox num={1} color='white' position='middle-right' />
        </View>
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
          <SmallBox num={1} color='white' position='bottom-left' />
          <SmallBox num={1} color='white' position='bottom-middle' />
          <SmallBox num={1} color='white' position='bottom-right' />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }

  renderBottom(color) {
    return (
      <View
        ref={(component) => (this.refViewBottom = component)}
        style={[styles.rectangle, color ? { backgroundColor: color } : null]}
        {...this.panResponder.panHandlers}
      >
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
          <SmallBox num={1} color='orange' position='top-left' />
          <SmallBox num={1} color='orange' position='top-middle' />
          <SmallBox num={1} color='orange' position='top-right' />
        </View>
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
          <SmallBox num={1} color='orange' position='middle-left' />
          <SmallBox num={1} color='orange' position='middle-middle' />
          <SmallBox num={1} color='orange' position='middle-right' />
        </View>
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
          <SmallBox num={1} color='orange' position='bottom-left' />
          <SmallBox num={1} color='orange' position='bottom-middle' />
          <SmallBox num={1} color='orange' position='bottom-right' />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#fff5c0' }}>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          {this.renderLeft('blue')}
          {this.renderRight('yellow')}
          {this.renderFront('red')}
          {this.renderBack('green')}
          {this.renderTop('white')}
          {this.renderBottom('orange')}
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

This is utils.js:

```
import MatrixMath from 'react-native/Libraries/Utilities/MatrixMath';

export const rotateXY = (dx, dy) => {
  const radX = (Math.PI / 180) * dy;
  const cosX = Math.cos(radX);
  const sinX = Math.sin(radX);

  const radY = (Math.PI / 180) * -dx;
  const cosY = Math.cos(radY);
  const sinY = Math.sin(radY);

  return [
    cosY,
    sinX * sinY,
    cosX * sinY,
    0,
    0,
    cosX,
    -sinX,
    0,
    -sinY,
    cosY * sinX,
    cosX * cosY,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    1,
  ];
};

export const rotateXZ = (dx, dy) => {
  const radX = (Math.PI / 180) * dx;
  const cosX = Math.cos(radX);
  const sinX = Math.sin(radX);

  const radY = (Math.PI / 180) * dy;
  const cosY = Math.cos(radY);
  const sinY = Math.sin(radY);

  return [
    cosX,
    -cosY * sinX,
    sinX * sinY,
    0,
    sinX,
    cosX * cosY,
    -sinY * cosX,
    0,
    0,
    sinY,
    cosY,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    1,
  ];
};

//source: https://gist.github.com/jmurzy/0d62c0b5ea88ca806c16b5e8a16deb6a#file-foldview-transformutil-transformorigin-js
export const transformOrigin = (matrix, origin) => {
  const { x, y, z } = origin;

  const translate = MatrixMath.createIdentityMatrix();
  MatrixMath.reuseTranslate3dCommand(translate, x, y, z);
  MatrixMath.multiplyInto(matrix, translate, matrix);

  const untranslate = MatrixMath.createIdentityMatrix();
  MatrixMath.reuseTranslate3dCommand(untranslate, -x, -y, -z);
  MatrixMath.multiplyInto(matrix, matrix, untranslate);
};
```

This is SmallBox.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableOpacity,
  TouchableHighlight,
} from 'react-native';

export default function SmallBox({ num, position, color }) {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      style={styles.smallBox}
      onPress={() => console.log(color, position)}
    >
      <Text>{num}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  smallBox: {
    margin: 0.2,
    height: 100 / 3,
    width: 100 / 3,
    borderWidth: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});
```

[This is the component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pFqR.png)

Comment: Could it be possible that the  click is "passing through" your component and clicking on the other side of the cube?

Comment: WIt’s possible - the opposite side is firing the event.. how do I check? Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: You could render just one side of the cube and check if all colors trigger correctly. If they do, then it's likely triggering from the other side. Also add an id to each side of the grid, as in (31,32,33, where the the house of the tenths is a side and the unit is 1-9) and console log that.